# What is the max size for an array to be uploaded using gl.uniform1fv?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

Is there any limit on the above call? Is that limit different for WebGL 1.0 vs WebGL 2.0?
If there is no limit, would there be a reason to use that vs Textures for input  data?

thanks

Comment: Separate from @HankMoody's answer textures can be sampled, textures can have mips, in WebGL2 textures can be 3D so there's lots of reasons to use textures for data over uniforms separate from the fact that you don't get that many uniforms.

Comment: Thanks @gman for weighing in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For vertex shaders the maximum size is specified by the `gl.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` parameter. 
Minimum for [WebGL 1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGet.xml) is **128**.
Minimum for [WebGL 2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGet.xhtml) is **256**.

```
gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS);
```

For fragment shaders the maximum size is specified by the `gl.MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS` parameter. 
Minimum for [WebGL 1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGet.xml) is **16**.
Minimum for [WebGL 2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGet.xhtml) is **224**.

```
gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS);
```

You can quickly check these limits in your browser on the [Webgl Report](http://webglreport.com/) site.

**Note:** Other uniform variables decrease that limits and for example a `mat4` uniform in a shader counts as 4 uniforms.